# Symbols to represent a string scala

Tags: scala

I went through the answer on [Purpose of Scala's Symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554362/purpose-of-scalas-symbol)

I want to create a Symbol but it has space in it.

Ex:

```
val s = "Hello World"
val syb = 'Hello World
```

`syb` gives compile time error. Is it possible to create a Symbol with spaces?

Comment: `'foo` is simply syntactic sugar for `Symbol("foo")`. And that's not an implementation detail, AFAIK it is explicitly defined that way in the Scala Language Specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to create a `Symbol` with spaces with the `Symbol.apply` method:

```
scala> val syb = Symbol("Hello World")
syb: Symbol = 'Hello World
```

Comment: Rather annoying that the Symbol class' `toString` doesn't have a special case for these symbols. Printing `'Hello World` is incredibly ugly.