# What does 'foo mean in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax, scalatest

For example, scalatest says that to check whether an `Option` is defined or not, I should use an expression like

```
val opt: Option[String] = ...
opt should be ('defined)
```

Since `Option` has `isDefined`, this either API design or actually an exotic reference to the said function... but I'd like to know how this works.

Comment: It's a [symbol](http://daily-scala.blogspot.nl/2010/01/symbols.html). I once asked [what the use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324466/practical-examples-of-using-symbols-in-scala) of this is in Scala, and I'm still not convinced that it's a very useful feature.

Comment: It defines a Symbol in Scala. Relevant:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780287/what-are-some-example-use-cases-for-symbol-literals-in-scala

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324466/practical-examples-of-using-symbols-in-scala

Comment: @Jesper I think symbols are sort-of Scala version of Erlang atoms.

Comment: @ghik in fact [clojure's keyword](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Keywords) is more closely related to scala symbols -- they have the very same implementation mechanism (interned strings)

Answer (score 1):

Combining the comments to the question and some quick experiments, here's what I've learned:

The syntax `'foo` is simply a shortcut for calling a lookup-or-create factory method that returns `Symbol` instances.

Symbols are not glorified aliases for strings; one cannot simply use a Symbol instance as a String.

Not all strings can be symbols. White spaces, escapes etc are not valid characters in a symbol.

API designers can use these characteristics. In the OP, scalatest's matchers were asking for a function name not as a string, but as a Symbol. They are essentially overloading the `be` function --

```
// String; actually AnyRef -- treat as a value comparison
string1 should be ("defined")  

// calls the method on option1 and checks whether output == true
option1 should be ('defined)
```